# Symfony Error 500 when create query by find() or findlALL()

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

When I execute this query I get correct result

```
    $entity = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Visits')
                 ->countDoctorVisits(13, '2013-03-01', '2013-05-30');
```

But If look like this

```
$entity = $em->getRepository('SurgeryPatientBundle:Visits')->findAll();
```

I get Error 500,  **/var/log/mysql.err is** empty also `/var/log/mysql.log`

What and how I should show ? And how fixed this

Comment: Do you have own repository class?

Comment: If you run your Symfony app in the dev environment (`app_dev.php`) you'll get fantastic information from the error message which will help you and/or us.

Comment: check `app/logs/prod.log`

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and it was an error in the doctrine cache. Double check that your cache directory and all sub directories have the 755 rights

To be more specific, it was not able to write one of the proxy files in the directory app\cache\dev\doctrine\orm\Proxies...
Creating it manually also worked (to have the filename, look into the log file)